# Ruby class initialize error - undefined method 'has_key?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I was following this [Balanced Payments tutorial](http://old.nycdevshop.com/blog/balanced-payments-part-1), and tried tweaking their Payment model to fit my application.

Original:

```
class Payment

  def initialize(email, amount, credit_card_hash)
    @email = email
    @amount = (amount * 100).to_i
    @credit_card_hash = credit_card_hash
    @buyer = nil
    @card = nil
    @errors = []
  end

end
```

My simplified version (Updated with code of full model):

```
require 'balanced'

class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_reader :errors, :amount

  def initialize(amount)
    @amount = (amount * 100).to_i
    @buyer = nil
    @card = nil
    @errors = []
  end

    def charge
      begin
        find_or_create_buyer
        debit_buyer
        credit_owner
        return true
      rescue
        return false
      end
    end

  private    

  def find_or_create_buyer
      begin
        @buyer = current_user.balanced_customer
      rescue
        @errors << 'Your account is invalid'
      end
  end

  def debit_buyer
    begin
      payment = @buyer.debit(@amount, "Test transaction")
    rescue
      @errors << 'Your credit card could not be charged'
    end
  end

  def credit_owner
    begin
      Balanced::Marketplace.my_marketplace.owner_account.credit(amount)
    rescue
      @errors << 'Your credit card payment did not go through.'
    end
  end


end
```

The problem is I'm getting what seems like a pure ruby error every time I try to instantiate the class from the rails console,

```
> payment = Transaction.new(0.01)
 output error: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `has_key?' for nil:NilClass>
```

I've googled around and haven't been able to come up with a good answer.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there more to the stack trace/error message? Does it say which line or anything?

Comment: Negative, I was running the test in the rails console, updated my question.

Comment: We might need to see the code for `Transaction` as well, then. The error means that something somewhere is trying to call `has_key?` on a variable (most likely expecting a `Hash`) that is `nil`.

Comment: My mistake, the name of the class was changed as well in the tweak.  It's the same thing in this case.  I'll update with code for the full model.

Comment: Yeah I was about to say, please search for the has_key? and show us _that_ code

Comment: You might need to escape the `?` in the search for example `/?`

Comment: From http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html: "Active Records accept constructor parameters either in a hash or as a block." Does the example pass the parameters as a hash/named parameters (e.g. `payment = Transaction.new(amount: 0.01)`)? (I'm not sure if this actually applies, but taking a stab.)

Comment: undefined method `*' for {:amount=>0.01}:Hash

Comment: Yeah, it was a long shot (and didn't really seem consistent with how Ruby works anyway). Unfortunately, I'm not a Rails guy so I don't know if there's something deeper that's causing this. It's a shame the console doesn't give any more of an error message.

Comment: Guess I'll call it a day and use another method.  Throw me an upvote to get my question back to zero, and answer with with something along the lines of "no idea, good luck", I'll accept it.  partial-win win.  Down voters need to cool their guns.

Comment: I'll just leave "No idea, good luck" as a comment so you can delete this question if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In active record initialization is done with a hash of attributes and you are overriding the initializer

http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2007/1/22/using-faux-accessors-to-initialize-values

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out when I get the chance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this seems to stop the error, whatever the hell I did.

Not sure if this will cause any problems later, we'll see.

```
  def initialize(args = {})
    super
    @my_cache = {}
    @amount = args[:amount]
    @buyer = nil
    @card = nil
    @errors = []
  end
```